# Python Automatically Inserts A New Line Problem

Tags: python

Ok so guys, I have a problem where when I use + in a string or in a writefile, it starts on a new line.
`hello = '"' + hello.readline() + '"'`
any way to fix this?

Comment: your issue might be that hello.readline() contains a \n character so try. hello.readline().replace("\n", "")

Comment: Yes, this was my issue thank you for helping me!

Comment: …or rather `hello.readline().rstrip()`